# PHP/Nginx error(Win)

Tags: php, windows, nginx

I get this error message on Nginx ws:

**Error.log:**
2012/07/23 21:20:33 [alert] 368#3636: *2045 1024 worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/index.php", host: "127.0.0.1"

**Page output:**
The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later.

OS: WinXp(SP3)

**Config:**

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  logs/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  60;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:80;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors        on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort     off;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, [a worker can handle only 1024 simultaneous connections](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html). Increase the number of `worker_processes` if you need to handle more connections than this, or use nginx on a non-Windows operating system.